Matlab Convert Stuct of Nodes to Node Array
I'm looking to read a large number of nodes from an OPC_UA server using
[val] = readValue(uaClient,read_nodes_test)

For tidiness sake, i've got my nodes stored in a struct which i've called OPC_UA_nodes. The issue is i cannot find a way to convert this struct of nodes to the node array required for the readvalue command.
All documentation encourages me to use struct2cell and then cell2mat, however cell2mat does not support cell arrays containing cell arrays or objects.
What is the best way to create the node array? Besides
nodes = [node1, node2, node3,..., node75]


I don’t know if the answer below answers your question or not. Because it is unclear to me exactly what you are asking. If it does answer it, just give it the green tick mark and we can move on. Otherwise, please [edit] your post to include exactly what data structure you have and what you want to have. Preferably by including a bit of code that mocks up a representative example of the struct you currently have.

@Cris happy for OP to clarify further, but I interpreted they're using this readValue function where the 2nd input nodeList is an array of OPC UA Node objects. In my answer I made a struct of such node objects, and then output them as a concatenated array which would be suitable for readValue, without having to list them individually as in OP's last line.

You can use structfun to iterate over all of the fields in OPC_UA, and if the function you supply is just @(x)x then the node within that struct field will be returned. Since they're all scalar objects which can be concatenated into an array, they will be.
Example setup:
OPC_UA = struct();
OPC_UA.node1 = opcuanode(1, 'node1');
OPC_UA.node2 = opcuanode(2, 'node2');
OPC_UA.node3 = opcuanode(3, 'node3');

Using structfun to get all of the nodes into an array:
nodes = structfun( @(x)x, OPC_UA );


A more verbose way of doing this which would let you be selective about which fields of OPC_UA you use would be something like this, looping over the field names with dynamic struct.(fieldname) syntax:
fn = fieldnames( OPC_UA );
nodes = opc.ua.Node.empty(0,1);
for i = 1:numel(fn)
    nodes(i,1) = OPC_UA.(fn{i});
end

